# Crux of linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, big-picture

What is the connection between solving systems of linear equations and vector spaces? And what do matrices have to do with all of that?

I know this is a crux of linear algebra, and therefore, not so specific question but I need a motivation approach for what linear algebra is. Thanks.

Comment: A system of linear equations can be written as $Ax=b$, where $A$ is a matrix and $x$ and $b$ are vectors

Comment: What you refer to as systems of linear equations can be studied using matrices, and the elementary results concerning existence of solutions for these equations can be stated in the language of matrices.

Vector spaces can be rather abstract, but in finite dimensions, using a basis allows you to write (linear) problems in those vector spaces in terms of linear systems of equations, and matrices.

Answer (score 1):

Vector spaces and linear maps arise in a lot of ways when dealing with systems of linear equations:

Note that you can write any linear system as $Ax = b$ where $A \in \Bbb R^{n,m}, x \in \Bbb R^m, b \in \Bbb R^n$ (considering the simple case where we have a linear system with real numbers). Assume you have some solution $x_0$ of this system and another vector $\hat{x}$ such that $A \hat{x} = 0$, then clearly $x_0+\alpha\hat{x}$ is also a solution of your system since $A(x_0 + \alpha\hat{x}) = Ax_0 + \alpha A\hat{x} = b + \alpha 0 = b$ for all $\alpha \in \Bbb R$.

Note that in particular for the case $b=0$ we have that you can multiply any two solutions by some factor, add them up and you'll still have a solution for the original system. So the set of all solutions of $Ax=0$ is a vector space - and the set of all solutions of $Ax=b$ is a so called affine space where the underlying vector space is precisely the solution set of $Ax=0$.

Answer (score 0):

A system of linear equations is a vector equation that expresses that you know the image of some vector by a given *linear transformation*, and you are looking for the components that unknown vector.

Consider a linear transformation from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^m$. Any vector of $\mathbb R^n$ can be expressed as a linear combination of the elements of the canonical basis (unit vectors along every axis). And by linearity of the transformation, the image of a linear combination is the same linear combination applied to the images. (This is where vector spaces appear.)

Now the images of the canonical vectors are $n$ vectors of dimension $m$, and the above reasoning shows that the linear transformation is completely determined by $n\times m$ numbers. These numbers can be arranged in a 2D array. (This is where matrices appear.)